# Java - Connecting two machines on same network

Tags: java, linux, sockets, connection, client

I want to simply connect two machines on the same network via a TCP Server/Client socket connection.

Right now, I need the IPv4 address from the machine hosting the server in order to connect the client.

localhost works fine when I'm running the server and the client on the same computer, but that's not very useful.

Is there any way around having to manually punch in the IPv4 of the host computer?

Thanks, this will probably clear up a lot of confusion.

Comment: are they both in the same lan or do you want a coonection via internet?

Comment: They're connected to the same LAN yes

Answer (score 0):

Use a broadcast to send all clients a message. (this could contain the servers IP but think about that! it could be a security issue)

There are good examples on sending broadcast messages with java

- [Broadcasting to Multiple Recipients](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/broadcasting.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the hosts, then you can also pass these names in a config file and use getaddrinfo() to get the IP address of the host: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html . Since hostnames do not chnage frequently, this should provide good improvement as compared to manually punching the IP address.